# Adding Duplicated array values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I Have an array `[[Food , quantity]]` with duplicated values and i want to add the quantities of the same food in the array but i can't seem to find a way to do that

I want to do this using JavaScript and the array looks like this:

```
[
  ["Burger", 5],
  ["Pizza", 10],
  ["Coke", 13],
  ["Burger", 7],
  ["Soda", 10],
  ["Pizza", 4],
  ["Burger", 12]
]
```

and i want the result to be like:

```
[
  ["Burger", 24],
  ["Pizza", 14],
  ["Coke", 13],
  ["Soda", 10]
]
```

And then I want to display the result on a table

Comment: Does the order of elements matter ? or it should be in some sorted manner ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most efficient method to groupby on a array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like -

```js
const arr = [["Burger" , 5], ["Pizza" , 10], ["Coke" , 13], ["Burger" , 7], ["Soda" , 10], ["Pizza" , 4], ["Burger" , 12]];

let ans = [];
arr.map((x) => {
 const [name, qty] = x;
  const found = ans.find((y) => y[0] === name);
  if(found){
   found[1] = found[1] + qty;
  } else {
   ans.push(x);
  }
});
console.log(ans);
```

Comment: How does this work? What does `map` do, for example?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to group each food. Create an accumulator with each `food` as key and the sum of quantity as value. If the key is already added, increment it. Else, add the key with quantity as value. Then use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get a 2D array of food - total quantity pairs

```js
const input=[["Burger",5],["Pizza",10],["Coke",13],["Burger",7],["Soda",10],["Pizza",4],["Burger",12]]

const counter = input.reduce((acc, [food, value]) => {
  acc[food] = acc[food] + value || value;
  return acc;
}, {});

const ouptut = Object.entries(counter)

console.log(JSON.stringify(ouptut))
```

This is what the accumulator/ counter object will look like:

```
{
  "Burger": 24,
  "Pizza": 14,
  "Coke": 13,
  "Soda": 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try out like,

```js
let array = [["Burger" , 5], ["Pizza" , 10], ["Coke" , 13], ["Burger" , 7], ["Soda" , 10], ["Pizza" , 4], ["Burger" , 12]];

let itemObj = {};

for(let item of array){
  if(itemObj.hasOwnProperty(item[0]))
    itemObj[item[0]] += item[1];
  else
    itemObj[item[0]] = item[1];
}

console.log(itemObj);

let newArray = Object.keys(itemObj).map(function(key) {
  return [key, itemObj[key]];
});

console.log(newArray);
```